# How to make android emulator access my PC files?

Tags: android

can anyone please tell me how can I make android emulator access the media files of my PC.I dont know how to make the connection between the two.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont think this is possible, but you can add files to an image file that you can mount as the SDcard in the emulator. Perhaps this serves for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this post for information about pushing files from you PC to the Android Emulator:

[how to import files into the sdcard on emulator in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506661/how-to-import-files-into-the-sdcard-on-emulator-in-android)

If you want to access them in runtime and not push the files there you have to have a public IP on the internet in which you can access and expose the files on HTTP with something like Apache Tomcat or FTP and then access that from the emulator.

You can also access it locally without exposing it to the whole internet, by accessing from the Android emulator to the "localhost" IP. You'll have to search which IP this is.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the adb command which comes in the tools dire of the SDK:

```
adb shell
```

It will give you a command line prompt where you can browse and access the filesystem. Or you can extract the files you want:

```
adb pull /sdcard/the_file_you_want.txt
```

Also, if you use eclipse with the ADT, there's a view to browse the file system

```
(Window->Show View->Other... and choose Android->File Explorer)
```

Comment: I think the question is the absolute oposite of what you answered.

Comment: I m sorry if the question was not clear...actually I have to develop an application Android Mobile Remote that can work as a remote to access the media files of any PC and I dont know how to make the connection between the phone and the PC.